# Resuse a variable in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, router, bunyan

I am trying to use(log) the return object of a function without decalring multiple variables

How best can this be done following `nodeJS`/`Javascript` best practice.

Do I have to declare this variable multiple times as I know it by reference.

```
var configuredRoute;
configuredRoute = router.route('/api/v1/people')
  .get(PersonController.all)
  .post(PersonController.add)

logger.configured(configuredRoute.methods,configuredRoute.path)

configuredRoute = router.route('/api/v1/people/:id')
  .get(PersonController.getOne)
  .put(PersonController.update)
  .delete(PersonController.remove)
logger.configured(configuredRoute.methods,configuredRoute.path)

configuredRoute = router.route('/api/v1/supervisor')
  .get(auth.isAuthenticated(), PersonController.allSupervisors)

logger.configured(configuredRoute.methods,configuredRoute.path)

configuredRoute = router.route('/api/v1/people/status/:phone')
  .get(PersonController.isRegistered)

logger.configured(configuredRoute.methods,configuredRoute.path)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to do multiple declarations ?

Comment: Cos I think there should be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking how to call `logger.configured` on the result of configuring each route without declaring more variables. One solution is to use anonymous functions to represent a route configuration:

```
//assuming logger and router are declared in this scope

function configureRoute(route) {
    const {methods, path} = route(router)
    logger.configured(methods, path)
}

const routes = [
    router =>
        router.route('/api/v1/people')
            .get(PersonController.all)
            .post(PersonController.add),
    router =>
        router.route('/api/v1/people/:id')
            .get(PersonController.getOne)
            .put(PersonController.update)
            .delete(PersonController.remove),
    router =>
        router.route('/api/v1/supervisor')
            .get(auth.isAuthenticated(), PersonController.allSupervisors),
    router =>
        router.route('/api/v1/people/status/:phone')
            .get(PersonController.isRegistered)
]

for (const route of routes) {
    configureRoute(route)
}
```